# Disable bridge module insert?

Tags: fedora, drivers, kernel-modules

I have Fedora 20 setup with default kernel configuration, where bridge feature is enabled as a module (`CONFIG_BRIDGE=m`), and the bridge module loads as the system starts. I don't understand who initiates it, since I have not found anything about `bridge.ko` in `/etc/sysconfig/modules/*`. However it ends up in the memory and every time I have to 'rmmod' it.

I would like to prohibit loading of the `bridge.ko` on the start up, yet I still want to manually load/unload `bridge.ko` whenever necessary.

I know it is possible to use the blacklist feature in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`, but can anybody point out who is loading `bridge.ko` in default setup of Fedora 20?

Comment: The most likely reason the bridge module is getting loaded is, the system is set up to be ready for hosting QEMU/KVM virtual machines; if `libvirt` is installed, there might even be a default bridge set up for handling network traffic between the host and any VMs that might be started on this host. If you don't need virtualization, there should be no problem tearing down the bridge functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the output of `lsmod` it'll typically tell you which modules are loaded due to being a dependency of some other module. For example, in the case of `bridge`, it looks like `stp` & `llc` required it.

```
$ lsmod | grep brid
bridge                116006  1 ebtable_broute
stp                    12868  1 bridge
llc                    13941  2 stp,bridge
```

**NOTE:** This is from my Fedora 20 system as well (laptop). You can use another tool, `modinfo` to find out information about the 2 modules:

```
$ modinfo stp
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.3-200.fc20.x86_64/kernel/net/802/stp.ko
license:        GPL
depends:        llc
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.3-200.fc20.x86_64 SMP mod_unload 
signer:         Fedora kernel signing key
sig_key:        55:46:C1:1D:28:CF:EC:0B:46:B1:C1:F1:93:0D:6B:F3:EC:63:B0:67
sig_hashalgo:   sha256

$ modinfo llc
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.3-200.fc20.x86_64/kernel/net/llc/llc.ko
description:    LLC IEEE 802.2 core support
author:         Procom 1997, Jay Schullist 2001, Arnaldo C. Melo 2001-2003
license:        GPL
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.3-200.fc20.x86_64 SMP mod_unload 
signer:         Fedora kernel signing key
sig_key:        55:46:C1:1D:28:CF:EC:0B:46:B1:C1:F1:93:0D:6B:F3:EC:63:B0:67
sig_hashalgo:   sha256
```

That didn't shed much more light on the situation, so let's see what Google has to say about "linux llc". Here's the project page and a synopsis of what this module is all about.

*excerpt - https://code.google.com/p/linux-llc/*

> linux-llc is a collection of programs that form the base set of the
>   Linux-LLC networking stack's userspace components for the Linux
>   operating system.
>
> Logical Link Control (LLC) is a sublayer of the IEEE 802.2 LAN
>   Protocol Suite. LLC is the top sub-layer in the data link layer and is
>   the common access method to the different medium access technologies
>   such as Tokenring, Ethernet and FDDI. LLC sockets provides a
>   convenient and easy to use method for accessing LLC1 and LLC2
>   functions from userspace.
>
> An LLC2 socket inherits all the functionality of an LLC1 socket. The
>   LLC1 socket uses the LLC datalink connectionless mode (Unacknowledged
>   data transfer) protocol. Verses an LLC2 socket uses the LLC datalink
>   connection oriented mode plus datalink connectionless mode.

So based on this information, I'd say this is a pretty core module, that you'll have a hard time removing and/or going without, especially if you're using any of the listed networking technologies.

Comment: I think you have things back to front - it was `bridge` that required `stp` and `llc` not the other way round. It was `ebtable_broute` that required `bridge` it seems.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `alias bridge off` inside `/etc/modprobe.d/disable_bridge.conf` will prevent loading the module.

Note that the name of the file can be anything, need to terminate with `.conf`.

```
$ echo "alias bridge off" >> /etc/modprobe.d/disable_bridge.conf
```